# I am running into an error while trying to install latest version of sktime

Tags: python, sktime

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sktime==0.5.2
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sktime==0.5.2
```

Comment: What command did you run?

Comment: Your question is unclear and will be hard for people to answer. To write a good question check out the [ask] guide and how to create a [mre].

Comment: i couldnt install it on windows 10 machine with or without virtualenv, my atempt in ubuntu desktop 18.04 was succesfull under virtualenv both runned with python 3.8 and current pip version, also it doesnt work with pipenv –